# creating or updating rows from csv file with async await, creates more than one row instead of updating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv, mongoose, async-await

I am facing some problem how to use async/await or promises in this context. I am new to Node.js. I am following this two post from MongoDB to add time series data.

1. [Link 1](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb)
2. [Link 2](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/time-series-data-and-mongodb-part-2-schema-design-best-practices)

I am using async Stream [readableSymbol.asyncIterator](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_symbol_asynciterator)

Sample CSV

```
date,symbol,open,close,low,high,volume
2016-01-05 00:00:00,WLTW,123.43,125.839996,122.309998,126.25,2163600.0
2016-01-06 00:00:00,WLTW,125.239998,119.980003,119.940002,125.540001,2386400.0
2016-01-07 00:00:00,WLTW,116.379997,114.949997,114.93,119.739998,2489500.0
2016-01-08 00:00:00,WLTW,115.480003,116.620003,113.5,117.440002,2006300.0
```

Schema

```
const stockSchema = new Schema({
  symbol: { type: String, required: true },
  date: { type: Date, required: true },
  values: {}
});
```

I want to store data in a following way:

```
{
"symbol": "WLTW",
"date": {
    "$date": "2015-12-31T18:30:00.000Z"
},
"values": {
    "8": {
        "open": "115.480003",
       ....

    },
    "5": {
        "open": "122.43",
       ....

    }
  }
}
```

Here in the date field I am storing month and year and in values field I am storing day values of that month as mentioned in the above post from Mongo db. Such that I can get the whole month data at once.

APP.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');

const readFile = async () => {
  let readable = fs
    .createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'data/data.csv'))
    .pipe(csv());
  for await (const row of readable) {
    const stockObj = createStockObj(row);
    insertIntoMongo(stockObj);
  }
};

const createStockObj = stockData => {
  const { date, symbol, open, close, low, high, volume } = stockData;
  const dateVal = new Date(date);
  const year = dateVal.getFullYear();
  const month = dateVal.getMonth();
  const day = dateVal.getDate();
  return {
    symbol,
    date: new Date(year, month),
    values: {
      [day]: { open, close, low, high, volume }
    }
  };
};

const insertIntoMongo = async newStock => {
  const { symbol, date, values } = newStock;
  let stock = await Stock.findOne({ symbol, date });
  if (stock === null) {
    let newStockValue = new Stock(newStock);
    console.log('Create');
    await newStockValue.save();
  } else {
    console.log('Update');
    stock.values = { ...stock.values, ...newStock.values };
    await stock.save();
  }
};

mongoose
  .connect(
    dbURI,
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
  )
  .then(() => {
    console.log('db connected');
    readFile();
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The log which I am getting is

```
Create
Create
Create
Create
```

Expectation:

```
Create
Update
Update
Update
```

The problem I am facing here is more than 1 insertion is happening for same symbol and date. Even though I am using async await, its not waiting for the first create to happen and then find the next one. Or the function is getting called.

My `insertIntoMongo` function is not working correctly as new records with same value is getting created and update is not getting saved even though debugger is hitting there.